# Why does the following code snippet close STDOUT?

Tags: c, operating-system, stdout, file-descriptor

I'm looking at my professor's code (provided a template for a previous project) for a command-line random number generator. At the end of the code, he does the following:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ...

  if (fclose (stdout) != 0)
    output_errno = errno;

  if (output_errno)
    {
      errno = output_errno;
      perror ("output");
    }

  finalize ();
  return !!output_errno;
}
```

I've never really been certain why. However, now I am faced with designing a UNIX Pipe for another project, and the instructions state:

> You may notice your program hanging waiting for input. You must call close on any file descriptors not explictly used in your process. Failure to call close will inform the operating system you are not done with it, and it will never return end-of-file from a read system call.

However, input is not output, so I'm wondering why. Any ideas?

Comment: This is all wrong. When the process exits, all its file descriptors are closed. And if the process exits normally, all stdio streams are flushed and closed.

Comment: It's not normal to close any of the `stdXXX` streams when the program ends. You should close any files the program explicitly opened.

Comment: @Barmar: Re “It's not normal to close any of the stdXXX streams when the program ends”: It is entirely normal if you want to check that the output was complete.

Comment: I don't think the comment you quoted from the project instructions is related to the code you show.  There may be reasons to manually close files at program termination, but any files that are not closed manually will be closed automatically by the OS.

Comment: They are unrelated, and I stated so. I gave the code snippet as an example of a time I've seen it done, and the project instructions as an example of what I am now facing.

Comment: Well no, you did not state so.  On the contrary, you suggested that you at least think they *might* be related by putting both in the question.  If you're indeed satisfied that the instructions about closing files do not explain the code presented, then why even bring it up?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: They did state so; the post states “However, now I am faced with designing a UNIX Pipe **for another project**…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil, in no way does a statement that the comments in question are associated with another project than the preceding code say that they are unrelated to what apparently is the actual subject of the question into which they have been inserted.

Comment: I brought it up because they were both about closing file descriptors, and I'm a beginner in low-level programming, so I was not sure of the relation.

Comment: It's ok to be unsure.  Indeed, I initially took you to be unsure about the relationship, which is exactly why I commented that there isn't one.  I thought that was responsive to the very uncertainty that you now say you indeed had.  So "thanks for clearing that up" would have been a welcome, and apparently appropriate response.  I will say no more about this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil While that's certainly possible, I would hardly call it "normal". If you search through all the GNU utilities, how many of them do this before exiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the following code snippet close STDOUT?

If the program is writing output to a file, as happens when standard output is redirected to a file in a shell command, it can fail because a disk is full, because a network volume becomes unavailable or a disk is forcibly unmounted or physically removed by a user, or for other reasons. This is not always made known to the program earlier, as ordinary calls such as `printf` buffer their output. Calling `fclose` and checking the result gives the program an opportunity to inform the user that the output was not completely written, by writing a message to the standard error stream and by returning a non-zero exit status to the calling environment (in the return from `main`).

> You may notice your program hanging waiting for input… it will never return end-of-file from a read system call.

Pipes between multiple processes are often created by opening a pipe, forking to create a new process, and closing the read side of the pipe in one process and the write side of the pipe in the other. As long as the write side of a pipe is open in any process, there is a possibility (from the point of view of the operating system), that the process could write data into the pipe, so the operating system keeps any process reading the pipe waiting for potential data. Only when all processes have closed the write side of a pipe will the operating system inform readers that there is no more data.

Comment: This program only takes command-line arguments. The second snippet is referring to our implementation for a UNIX PIPE `|` operator and is unrelated to the code for the first. Thanks for your response on the first bit, I suspect that's what my professor was aiming to do.

Comment: The full instructions read: `Given you are just using the executable names, you may use the C library helper functions for execve, such as execlp. execlp will let you skip using string arrays (using C varargs), and it will also search for executables using the PATH environment variable. You may notice your program hanging waiting for input. You must call close on any file descriptors not explictly used in your process. Failure to call close will inform the operating system you are not done with it, and it will never return end-of-file from a read system call.`

Comment: @user129393192: Updated. You should not ask separate questions in one post; use two posts.